# Find closest element on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, nested, event-propagation

I trigger a function by click on a nested element. To prevent bubbling I could use `e.stopPropagation();`.

If stop propagation, other scripts have trouble because they rely on bubbling on these elements. Is there another way around it? Some kind of if statement?

**html**

```
<div class="nested-element">
  <div class="nested-element">
    content
  </div>
  content
</div>
```

The nesting is in real life unlimited.

**jquery**

```
$('.selector').on('click', '.nested-element', function(e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

The above will output the root parent first and then move closer to the closest element. I only want to get the closest element.

Comment: then use `.parent()`

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cd1gt6p6/

Comment: might want `.closest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the `target` and if target is in a descendant instance of the class do nothing

```js
$(document).on('click', '.nested-element', function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).closest('.nested-element').not(this).length){
     console.log('nested-element clicked =', this.id);
   }else{      
     console.log('Ignore parent event')
   }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="nested-element">
  <div id="child" class="nested-element">
    child content
  </div>
  parent content
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work with unlimited nested elements as well, great! As an addition for other people, there is a great article about the topic in general: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/